# Can't get the password input field in template using ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, model

models.py:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    password_token = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='0')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_token_expiry = models.DateTimeField()
    tos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_action = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    passwordrepeat = forms.PasswordInput()

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')
        widgets = {
            'password' : forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        passwordrepeat = cleaned_data.get("passwordrepeat")
        if password != passwordrepeat:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match.")

        return cleaned_data
```

In template I get

```
username
password
email
```

I can't get the `passwordrepeat` input field in template. And how can I set the label for 'passwordrepeat' field. The label would be `Repeat Password`

And can I omit the `def clean` from `UsersModelForm`. I want to compare `password` and `repeatpassword` in views.py not in models.py.

views.py:

```
def register(request):
    flag = True
    possible = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    token = ''
    tempToken = ''

    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    user = UsersModelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userf = UsersModelForm(request.POST)
        username = userf.data['username']
        password = userf.data['password']
        passwordrepeat = userf.data['passwordrepeat']
        email = userf.data['email']

        tempSalt = bcrypt.gensalt()
        password = bcrypt.hashpw(password,tempSalt)
        passwordrepeat = bcrypt.hashpw(passwordrepeat,tempSalt)

        if password != passwordrepeat:
            flag = False
            passVariable = {'user':user, 'flag': False}
            return render_to_response('register.html', passVariable, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        elif password == passwordrepeat:
            for i in range(1,10):
                temp = random.choice(possible)
                token = token + temp

            if userf.is_valid():
                check = userf.save(commit=False)
                check.email_token = token
                check.email_token_expiry = current_datetime + timedelta(1)
                check.password = password
                check.passwordrepeat = passwordrepeat
                check.save()
                subject, from_email, to = 'hello', 'xxx@gmail.com', 'xxx@yahoo.com'
                text_content = 'This is an important message.'
                html_content = '<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/confirm/' + token + '">Click this link to confirm email</a>'
                msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
                msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
                msg.send()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('register.html', {"user": user, 'flag': True}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Could you dpaste the corresponding view?

Comment: I updated the original post. See that again to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right answer: use [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/). And django built-in auth system. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer to your question: you don't see `passwordrepeat` because `forms.PasswordInput` is not a field, it's a widget. Widget can't be rendered without a field. You should use `CharField` with `PasswordInput` here. If you want to set label, set it, `label` argument looks good for this task.

```
passwordrepeat = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label=u'Repeat Password')
```

The form

```
class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UsersModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.keyOrder = ['username', 'password', 'passwordrepeat', 'email']

    # ... other fields and methods ...
```

Comment: Yes, i got the `passwordrepeat` field now, but the sequence of the fiedls are `1)username 2)password 3)email 4)passwordrepeat`. How can i make the sequence in this format? `1)username 2)password 3)passwordrepeat 4)email`

Comment: @guru `self.fields.keyOrder = ['username', 'password', 'passwordrepeat', 'email']`. Place it in overrided `__init__`

Comment: Where to add this line? `self.fields.keyOrder = ['username', 'password', 'passwordrepeat', 'email']` ?

Comment: And can i omit the `def clean:` method? I updated the original post. See that again to understand.

Comment: @guru Place it in form's overrided `__init__` as I said a comment before. :-) You can omit `clean` method, but why? It's a good pace for logic like that. And your view is a typical example of [fat controller](http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2008/12/03/the-fat-controller/) antipattern. It's much better to avoid it (that's why it's called antipattern :-))

Comment: What should i do to avoid making `fat controller`?

Comment: Which class will contain the `__init__` ? the `class Users` or the `class UsersModelForm` ?

Comment: @guru Place it in form's overrided `__init__` In form's overrided `__init__`. Form's overrided `__init__`. `__init__`  that belongs to the form. `__init__` which owner is form. Form. To avoid fat controllers you shouldn't make them fat. You should place all this logic in form's class.

Comment: I still can't understand. can you post complete code? I have added my code in the first original post/question. See that again to understand. I don't have any `forms.py` file. I have `models.py` and `views.py`.

Comment: `To avoid fat controllers you shouldn't make them fat. You should place all this logic in form's class.` there is no form class. Do you mean `class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):` of models.py?

Comment: @guru Yes, it's what I'm talking about. If you don't have form class what is `UsersModelForm`? And BTW why do you place it `models.py`? Anyway I answered your original question and this long discussion is becoming pointless. If you you have other specific questions about project layout, form field ordering or fat controllers – feel free to create new questions about them (but search first).

Comment: Then where should i have created `class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):` ?